# Visual 2012 List of Built in Snippets

Tags: visual-studio-2012, code-snippets

Where can I find a List of Built in Snippets for Visual Studio 2012?

I guess to make myself more clear.

Like when typing prop(tab)(tab)

I would like to have a list of what is already built in so I do not try to build a snippet for something that is already built in.

The folder /Documents/Visual Studio 2012/Code Snippets/

Seems to me to be the place to put your own code snippets.

I would like to print out a cheat sheet of all of them.  So like a PDF, Website, etc.

Comment: I found the 2010 - I can go from there...
http://donkeybridge.blogspot.com/2011/08/visualstudio-cheat-sheet-csharp-code.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Built in snippents are in the folder
 **%InstallRootLocation%\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\%lang%\Snippets\1033**

For example,
C# code snippets -> **%InstallRootLocation%\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\vc#\Snippets\1033**
C++ code snippets -> **%InstallRootLocation%\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\vc\Snippets\1033**

%%InstallLocation%% is usually `%Program Files%` on 32 bit, and  `%Program Files (x86)%` on 64 bit systems but can be customized during VS installation process.

Custom snippets are in the folder

**%Documents%\Visual Studio 2012\Code Snippets**.

Comment: I say your first post... I see them in the folder now is there a website that lists them all out so I can print like a cheat sheat?

Comment: i am not aware of any website. I knew it was in %documents% folder, but later searched in install location. This is not large, you can create the list yourself

Answer (score 2):

MSDN contains an html list of snippets by Visual Studio version: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z41h7fat.aspx